# Invalid verification code format

Tags: oauth

I am getting two errors that I am aware of. 
I am building a app that should allow me to post news and like. 
It is a plugin built by appery.io

On the Facebook side I identified the url of the page that the user would be redirected after login, example below the two errors are also listed below.

http://appery.io/app/view/ee34c582-cba8-4ea0-9236-572de16b20e4/FacebookPublishing_AfterLogin.html

```
{ 
"error": { 
"message": "Invalid verification code format.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 100 
} 
}


{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```